# Outlook - how to group by date ranges ("today", "last week" etc...) when grouping manually?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In Microsoft Outlook, when "Automatically group according to arrangement" is checked in the "Group by" dialog, messages are grouped according to their date range in the style "yesterday", "last week" etc...

[image: Screen capture]

However when I uncheck "Automatically group according to arrangement" and set "Received date" as the first grouping field, messages are grouped strictly by minute (i.e. there is one message per group).

This is also the case for other fields like "start date" (red flag indicator). For that field, when "Automatically group..." is checked, the groups will show a nice red flag icon, but when this field is manually set as a grouping field ("Group automatically" is not checked), no icon is shown and the groups are by date instead of loose date ranges.

How to group manually by "loose" date ranges ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that you need to enable "Automatically group according to arrangement" for the date range but not manually.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It is helpful but it's not the solution I'm looking for. I need to set manual grouping criteria.